# sentry not catching native crushes in react-native

Tags: sentry

I already asked on the sentry-react-native git but no reply yet. I have the following crush:[image: java crush]

https://github.com/temharay/sentry

Sentry.nativeCrush() does get reported and I was hoping to see the above crush as well but I don't see it in my dashboard. Is there a difference in terms of crushes it catches?

JS crushes such as the following do get caught:

```
       nullVariable.toString();
```

But not crushes that come from the native java side of things.

I am on emulator android if it makes a difference. My setup is:

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/react-native';

Sentry.init({
  dsn: 'https://...@sentry.io/...'
  // other options
  enableAutoSessionTracking: true,
  enableNative: true,
  enableNativeCrashHandling: true,
  enabled: true,
  debug: true,
  integrations: [
    new Sentry.BrowserIntegrations.GlobalHandlers({
      onerror: true,
      onunhandledrejection: true,
    }),
  ],
});
```

On app load, I see the log:

```
[Wed Sep 30 2020 13:59:40.750]  LOG      Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: ReactNativeErrorHandlers
[Wed Sep 30 2020 13:59:40.752]  LOG      Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: Release
[Wed Sep 30 2020 13:59:40.752]  LOG      Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: InboundFilters
[Wed Sep 30 2020 13:59:40.753]  LOG      Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: FunctionToString
[Wed Sep 30 2020 13:59:40.753]  LOG      Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: Breadcrumbs
[Wed Sep 30 2020 13:59:40.754]  LOG      Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: LinkedErrors
[Wed Sep 30 2020 13:59:40.754]  LOG      Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: UserAgent
[Wed Sep 30 2020 13:59:40.755]  LOG      Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: DebugSymbolicator
[Wed Sep 30 2020 13:59:40.755]  LOG      Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: RewriteFrames
[Wed Sep 30 2020 13:59:40.756]  LOG      Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: DeviceContext
[Wed Sep 30 2020 13:59:40.756]  LOG      Sentry Logger [Log]: Global Handler attached: onerror
[Wed Sep 30 2020 13:59:40.757]  LOG      Sentry Logger [Log]: Global Handler attached: onunhandledrejection
[Wed Sep 30 2020 13:59:40.757]  LOG      Sentry Logger [Log]: Integration installed: GlobalHandlers
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that's removing the other integrations and setting a new list with only these browser support:

```
 integrations: [
    new Sentry.BrowserIntegrations.GlobalHandlers({
      onerror: true,
      onunhandledrejection: true,
    }),
  ],
```

Just try removing this code snippet.
Hard crashes get sent once the app restarts.

Comment: thanks Bruno. Even with that, it doesn't catch the hard exception

Comment: I suggest you create a small reproducible example, push that to github and link that repository to your issue. This will help folks verify what's going on

Comment: iirc native crashes are not captured if debug mode is enabled (by seeing this black screen for example), you actually need a release build that makes your app fully crash, then you get a Sentry event on the dashboard.